# Precompiled ROOT.war for Openshift not being deployed

Tags: java, maven, openshift

I need to have my precompiled ROOT.war deployed in my Openshift app.

Under the complete path of the war is `/deployments/ROOT.war`

I've checked this war file before doing git push that the `/app/app.nocache.js` is there. This js file is there in the index.html. Now when I access the app online, the index.html cannot find this js file. So it means the pre-compiled ROOT.war was not deployed, instead it seems it built a new ROOT.war.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove pom.xml and src folder from your cloned repo as corey112358 said
2. then put your war file into webapps folder (direct subfolder of your repo)
3. do the git:
   git add --all
   git commit -m"another commit"
   git push
4. watch the output for "found port..." to make sure your tomcat restarted fine

Remember that the war file does not get expanded (unzipped) in openshift.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading through this article on help.openshift.com about deploying pre-compiled war files and see if that helps (https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740-How-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-WAR-and-EAR-files-onto-your-OpenShift-gear-using-the-java-cartridges).

You are possibly not removing the pom.xml and src directories if it's building a new root.war file.